# The expression 'not that bad of a'

Tags: phrases, prepositions

In an essay, a friend used the expression:

> It wasn't that bad **of an** idea.

I think that it would be preferable to write

> It wasn't that bad **an** idea

However, I can't explain why.

Comment: Or, ***for** an idea*

Comment: Related (possible dupe): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30011/8019

Comment: It is not an expression I would use, but I have observed that many people do say it. I think they are predominantly American.

Comment: @Kris using `for` means that ideas are not generally great, but in the context of ideas it is decent.

Answer (score 1):

[Of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Of) as a preposition is also:

> - used to indicate an appositive: *that idiot of a driver.*

[appositive](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/apposterm.htm):

> - A noun, noun phrase, or series of nouns placed next to another word or phrase to identify or rename it.

http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=Is+Obama+that+bad+of+a+President&word2=Am+I+that+bad+of+a+person

Comment: What has that to do with the question at hand?

Comment: Are you saying the example sentence is correct then?

Comment: Yes, that's what he's saying.  *that (adj/noun) of a (noun)* is an exceptionally common phrasing, but as phrased, it's not going to be the right register for a formal paper.

Comment: This Google fight link is I think more relevant [Is it that bad of an idea? vs.Is it that bad an idea?](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=Is+it+that+bad+of+an+idea%3F&word2=Is+it+that+bad+an+idea%3F)

Comment: I think OP is asking about the construction 'that bad of a', which appears to be quite frequent.

Comment: +1 When talking about _bings_ (spoil heaps) or _booms_ (on a derrick) _that bad a bing_ or _that bad a boom_ isn't as 'sensible' as _that bad of a bing_ or _that bad of a boom_.

Comment: The strings 'that idiot of a driver' and 'that bad of an idea' are not isoformal, even at the surface level.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the whole problem by using a more simple and direct construction such as "It wasn't *such a* bad idea."

Answer (score 0):

The "of" is superfluous and serves no purpose; in a sentence that is already kind of awkward to begin with, adding "of" just adds that much more ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the original sense is

> It is not such a bad idea that `condition`

But the speaker wishes to omit `condition` as it goes without saying.

He evidently still wishes to alluding to its existence, otherwise he could just say

> It is not such a bad idea.

We evidently need that **that** that badly.  But one cannot say

> It is not that a bad idea [NO]

An article after **that** implies we are starting a relative clause like

> It is not that a cat is a *bad* animal, but ...

So we need to push the article forward.  It still *must* appear before its noun, and moving the noun anywhere else gets weird fast.  So we are stuck with

> It is not that bad an idea.

This article between the noun and so closely related a word sounds odd.  (Note, not *of* a word, same issue.)  So we look around for constructions that allow it, like.

> He is a bull of a man.
>
> I am not much of a typist.

These **are not** parallel formations.  The first has two nouns, rather than a noun and an adjective and the other is not a direct modification, as I would never say

> I am a much typist.  [NO]

But the uncertainty makes people allow for, and forgive the padded construction, even though it is not strictly grammatical.  And we end up with

> It is not that bad of an idea.  [barely OK]

I would call this a minor error, but still an error.

The majority agrees by a good margin: [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+bad+of+an+idea%2C+that+bad+an+idea&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20bad%20of%20an%20idea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20bad%20an%20idea%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use it that way as in *that bad of an idea* because *that bad* is not a noun phrase.

You can use it in an adjectival sense implying 'a thing that's that bad:'

> It wasn't that bad **(for)** an idea.

That is, as an idea, it wasn't that bad (adjective).

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote so quickly but it might be that you haven't given any backup or provided any references. If you could, it's +1 from me.

Comment: Schadenfreude time!

Comment: Yes, it is. And I'm quite enjoying it! :)

Comment: @kris - not my downvote anyway.

Comment: Here's four Ngrams that disagree with your claim that you cannot say "that adjective of" ... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+bad+of%2C+that+small+of%2C+that+large+of%2C+that+fond+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20bad%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20small%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20large%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20fond%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @virmaior 1. *that fond of* has nothing to do with this. 2. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+bad+of+a%2C+that+bad+of+an&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: “It’s not that much of a problem” or “It’s not that big of a deal” are both exceedingly common, particularly in (informal) AmE, as is the asker’s quote. _Of_ here does not have the function of linking two noun phrases, and saying you ‘cannot’ use the construction flies in the face of actual language usage.

Comment: @Kris how does *that fond of* have nothing to do with this? I'm pretty sure *fond* is an adjective -- as in *I have fond memories of this conversation*. There seems to be a pattern: "that **adj** of X" where the *that* is an adverb indicating the phrase will indicate the degree of validity of the adjective with respect to X.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  But you would never say 'it is a much problem', so that is not a counterexample and you should say 'it is not that big a deal'.  Adding the 'of' makes you sound hickish, exactly because it is not strictly grammatical.

Comment: @virmaior  But those are different versions of 'fond', since one applies to you and the other to the thing of which you are fond.  'I am not fond of asparagus', is not related to 'fond asparagus'!  'It is not that bad an idea' is related to 'bad idea'.

Comment: @JonJayObermark not quite sure what you mean by *different versions of 'fond'*. Is one Windows 8 and the other Windows Me? The expression [not] {so/that} **adj** of indicates whether the adjectivally modified term attains the appropriate degree.

Comment: @JonJayObermark I'm also not really getting where you get the supposition that it *makes you sound hickish* to say *that X of Y*. The lack of the "of" sounds grammatically wrong to me or rather like it's the hickish version that suppresses the statement of the *of*.

Comment: I am not that fond of your ear, given your example of 'fond of'.  I my considered opinion there are two things going on here.  People are bothered by the (grammatically correct but unusual) article between the noun and its adjective, and they are influenced by constructions like "not much of a house" and "That moron of a waiter", which are logically unrelated to this one.  So they borrow the of.  Letting your influences wash together like this implies less well-considered grammar.

Comment: For folks who like trends over rules: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+bad+of+an+idea%2C+that+bad+an+idea&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20bad%20of%20an%20idea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20bad%20an%20idea%3B%2Cc0  The rule is that nouns and their adjectives are not separated by prepositions.

Comment: @virmaior If you are going to use statistics rather than rules, use them fairly. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+bad+of%2Cthat+small+of%2Cthat+large+of%2Cthat+fond+of%2C+that+bad+a%2C+that+small+a%2C+that+large+a%2C+that+fond+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20bad%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20small%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20large%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20fond%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20bad%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20small%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20large%20a%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JonJayObermark fair enough.