# ...this big OF a wave ...?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am used to asking

**How big was the wave?**

and answering

**The wave was this big.**

My question is that, I think, in the US, it is pretty common (I have heard the usage often) to ask

**How big OF a wave was it?**

and to answer

**It was this big OF a wave.**

Listen to 2:12 in this clip http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-31093276

I don't understand why the 'of' is there (Question 1) and I wonder whether this word pattern can be traced back to the time of the Mayflower (question 2).

Comment: I'm finding it quite difficult to find this construction in Google books even as near back as the 20th century (let alone in the time of the *Mayflower*), although there seem to be quite a number of 21st examples. So for (2), I'd say it's quite recent.

Comment: The Mayflower sailed in 1620 with 102 passengers and 30 crew. Can we blame this all on something 132 people did 395 years ago?

Comment: Please be clear, there is no judgment implied in my question.  I LIKE different ways of speaking, that's why I enjoy this site. Simply, I'm curious.

Comment: This seems to be an emerging pattern. I find “How big of a wave was it?” perfectly unobjectionable, but “How terrible of a time did you have?” jars, and “How exciting of a party was it?” is utterly ungrammatical to me. I wonder what the current limitations to the pattern are, and whether they are diminishing.

Comment: How successful of a President has Obama been ?

Comment: Possibly related: *[“How big of a problem” vs. “how big a problem”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011)*

Answer (score 3):

I have also noticed this construction, and only in the last few years. I think it may be a generalisation of the forms:
I felt like a bit of an idiot.
How much of an idiot am I?