# When may adjectives precede determiners? (E.g. too difficult of a task)

Tags: adjectives, word-order, determiners

The expression *too difficult a task* sounds a little pompous, but it doesn't sound ungrammatical. According to my folk-beliefs about English grammar, determiners precede adjectives. However, the expression *too difficult a task* seems to controvert that belief.

Additionally, the expression *too difficult **of** a task* seems grammatical too.

1. Under what conditions may determiners precede adjectives?
2. Are there conditions under which *too difficult of a task* would be a more grammatical expression than *too difficult a task* would be?

(This question does not ask what the question “How big of a problem” vs. “how big a problem” asks. That question does not pertain to determiners.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How big of a problem" vs. "how big a problem"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/how-big-of-a-problem-vs-how-big-a-problem)

Comment: @FF: Question (1) here is not answered, or even addressed, by those prior answers.  "Determiner" is not mentioned on the page. It's a fair question, correctly put, and I admit ***I*** don't know the answer to the general question. I'm a verb phrase linguist, not a noun phrase linguist.

Comment: *The expression too difficult a task sounds a little pompous* I'm not sure what gives you that impression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This construction seems to require a modifier that makes a comparison, such as *too*, *(not) as*, *more*, *equally*, *less*. Intensifiers which don't have this quality don't seem to do it: **very difficult a task* doesn't seem to work.

The construction with *of* is recent, and traditionalists don't regard it as grammatical. But it is clearly grammatical for some people (though not for me). I think it is predominently American, and I'm sure that it arose because of the unusualness of the traditional construction.