# Which sentence is correct (too+adj.)?

Tags: idioms, word-order

Which sentence is correct?

> *This object has a too low temperature.*
>
> *This object has too low a temperature.*

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question? (downvoted)

Comment: Related question, [When may adjectives precede determiners? (E.g. too difficult a task)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282574/when-may-adjectives-precede-determiners-e-g-too-difficult-a-task).

Comment: Hi MWijnand. Welcome to EL&U! Please wait a day or two before selecting an answer. You may get several more answers with other ideas or different advice. But people may not bother to write you another answer if you've already selected one! (you can unselect it for the time being by clicking on the green tick - you can put it back again later!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second choice is preferred.  One could also say "It has an excessively low temperature."

Plainer still is "It is too cold."

Comment: +1 for correctly pointing out the preferred choice, though it may improve your answer to explain why that's the preferred form.

Comment: @Rob_Ster - Indeed, but obviously, I wanted to know about the construction with too+adj. :)