# "Too great of a [risk]" OR "Too great a [risk]"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, writing-style, sentence-patterns

First, I want to emphasize that my question is general.

I want your answer regarding all of the cases in the following sentence stractures:

1. [Adjective] + of + [Noun] (For example: It is too great of a risk).
2. [Adjective] +  [Noun]  (For example: It is too great a risk).

I want to know if one of the sentence structures is considered informal. And, when should I use each of them?
Also, what is the difference between "too great of a risk" and "too great a risk"??

Here are some other examples I found on the internet:

> - You are too beautiful a woman and too happy a mother
> - It' s too beautiful of a day for you to be in a bad mood

> - There was nobody else in the world he would honor with so great a responsibility.
> - And you know how great a person she is.
> - I'm not that great of a person.

Comment: Do you want an answer for English as spoken in the UK or in the US? For this question, the answers are different.

Comment: I want to know the differences between UK English and US English. So, I'd like to get a detailed answer that explains how those constructions are being perceived by both US citizens and UK citizens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When may adjectives precede determiners? eg 'too difficult of a task'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282574/when-may-adjectives-precede-determiners-e-g-too-difficult-of-a-task) Or  ["How big of a problem" vs. "how big a problem"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/how-big-of-a-problem-vs-how-big-a-problem)

Comment: The "How big..." question is definitely a duplicate, but it gives a mistaken impression that "How big of a problem" is absolutely correct. It's perfectly acceptable, it seems, in American English, but it is definitely not universally accepted in British English.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth-  Yes. thanks!