# "too big a" vs "a too big"

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis, big-mess-construction

Here is the sentence I'm having a trouble with:

> ... a world that seems too big a place for any individual to contribute something unique.

Why does it say "too big a" and not "a too big"?

I apologize if something like this has been asked before but I didn't even know how to search for this.

Comment: See [Construction of “it's too hard a task”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7759/construction-of-its-too-hard-a-task) in ELL.SE.

Comment: See also: [“How big of a problem” vs. “how big a problem”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30011/50044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but 'too big a place' is much more poetical- a better expression than 'a too big place'.  The word 'too' rarely, if ever, has the article 'a' preceding it.  For example, 'That was too big a piece of pie' is correct, but 'That was a too big piece of pie' sounds funny to me.
 Hope this helps!