# How good an experience vs. How good of an experience

Tags: expression-choice

Which one of these sentences is considered to be more correct?

1) You cannot imagine how good an experience that has been.

or

2) You cannot imagine how good **of** an experience that has been.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that the second example is the 'more correct' one. One of the functions of the preposition (of) is describing a trait for a noun, in this case, you'll need it to show that (good) is an adjective which describes the experience. On the other hand, you might hear the first example in spoken English but i do not believe it is suitable for writing.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that "how good an experience" is acceptable in English writing, and from what I remember, the "how good of an" construction is traditionally actually considered less acceptable. I'll link to some related questions in a following comment.

Comment: Link: [“How big of a problem” vs. “how big a problem”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011)