# Unnecessary preposition "of" in qualifiers

Tags: american-english

I notice that people will use "of a"/"of an" when describing a quality of something, rather than "a"/"an" alone. I would only add the "of" in a quantifier. In my personal experience, it's more prevalent amongst American English speakers, which is supported by Ngram Viewer: [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bad+a%2Cbad+of+a%2Cgood+a%2Cgood+of+a%2Cbig+a%2Cbig+of+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) and [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bad+a%2Cbad+of+a%2Cgood+a%2Cgood+of+a%2Cbig+a%2Cbig+of+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3). It appears not to be dominant in either dialect.

Some examples:

> It's not that big of a deal.

vs.

> It's not that big a deal.

and

> He's not that good of an athlete.

vs.

> He's not that good an athlete.

I see it as bad grammar but am I wrong? In a quantifier it feels natural, e.g.:

> They didn't provide much of a meal.

---

People keep suggesting [this Q & A](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/how-big-of-a-problem-vs-how-big-a-problem) as a duplicate but, as per [my comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/584828/unnecessary-preposition-of-in-qualifiers/584943#comment1462520_584828) below, they are asking *why* there is a difference. I have already established that the difference is between qualitative and quantitative. Thanks for the downvotes, though.

Comment: Thanks, @livresque. I searched but didn't see that one. It's close; they're asking why it applies to some and not others, but I already know it's quantifying vs. qualifying. My question is asking whether using "of" in a qualifier is incorrect, and why (not).

Comment: The Dictionary.com quote gives caveats regarding acceptability.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, the *of* is perfectly natural.

In fact, I always sort of assumed that *It’s not that bigga deal* was a speech elision for *It’s not that big of a deal* — one that would perhaps be corrected to *of a* in formal writing.

It seems I had that exactly backwards. Grammarphobia says:

> . . . these dialectal “of a” usages are becoming acceptable idioms in
> casual speech and informal writing. However, we still wouldn’t
> recommend them in formal English, written or spoken.
>  <sub>Source:
> [Grammarphobia — Not that big of a
> deal?](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/01/not-that-big-of-a-deal.html)</sub>

However, Grammarphobia does add:

> It would be an understatement to call this idiom common in American
> speech. One linguist has written that for lots of speakers, it’s more
> than common—it’s preferred.

Here are some results from the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

[`that big of a deal`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=104553298) (439)

[`that big a deal`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=104553300) (462)

You can find comparable results there for:

[`that ADJ of a NOUN`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=104553282) (1,074 / unique 444)

[`that ADJ a NOUN`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=104553277) (1,322 / unique 630)

The Grammarphobia article was written eight years ago. In that time *that adj of a noun* has no doubt embedded itself deeper in the language.

See this Google Ngram for:

[`that big of a deal,that big a deal`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+big+of+a+deal%2Cthat+big+a+deal&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) (American English 1970–2019)

As an American editor, I imagine I would let stand *of a* if encountered, and possibly even “correct” *a* to *of a*.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed response, though I think "deal" is a poor noun choice as it's fairly casual. A better example would be that from the question others linked: "how big a problem" vs "how big of a problem", in [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+of+a+problem%2Cbig+a+problem&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbig%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbig%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0) and [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+of+a+problem%2Cbig+a+problem&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Walf: *that big of a problem* is more common than *that big a problem* in both COCA and Google Ngram American English.

Comment: We aren't looking at the same graphs. In Ngrams, I omitted "that" in the links to broaden the search, and the "of a" variant doesn't even appear until 1946. Adding "that" shows the "of a" variant only became dominant in 2010.

Comment: @Walf: Can you link to the Ngrams you are using?

Comment: The links are in my first comment. Adding "that" led to [this graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+big+of+a+problem%2Cthat+big+a+problem&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20big%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20big%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0) that shows the 2010 shift.

Answer (score 1):

Although adding an "of" is common in spoken English (at least in the U.S.), it is not considered proper grammar.